# Trying to GROUP BY to eliminate duplicate rows With 3 LEFT JOIN's

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to modify an existing query that is displaying duplicate rows sharing an ID, while having different secondary ID's.

```
SELECT  IM.*, C.Client, U.Name, R.FrequencyUnit, R.FrequencyDuration, R.RIID
FROM    itemsMisc IM
LEFT JOIN Clients C on C.ClientID = IM.ClientID
LEFT JOIN Users U on U.UserID = IM.UserID
LEFT JOIN Recurringitem R ON (R.ClientID = C.ClientID AND IM.Rate = R.Rate AND IM.Title = R.Title)
WHERE   (IM.CID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">) 
  AND   (IM.Invoiced = 0)
ORDER BY IM.DateCompleted ASC;
```

What's happening is if the same user makes 2 similar recurring items, a duplicate rows show up with the same IMID(from itemsMisc) but with different RIID's from Recurringitems.

I tried GROUP BY on IMID, found I had to include all of the select items in the GROUP BY, which got me no where.

```
SELECT IM.IMID, IM.UserID, IM.ClientID, IM.Rate, IM.Title, IM.CID, IM.QTY, IM.DateCompleted, C.Client, U.Name, R.FrequencyUnit, R.FrequencyDuration, R.RBID
FROM    ItemMisc IM
LEFT JOIN Clients C on C.ClientID = IM.ClientID
LEFT JOIN Users U on U.UserID = IM.UserID
LEFT JOIN Recurringitem R ON (R.ClientID = C.ClientID AND IM.Rate = R.Rate AND IM.Title = R.Title)
WHERE   (IM.CID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">) 
  AND   (IM.Invoiced = 0)
GROUP BY IM.IMID, IM.UserID, IM.ClientID, IM.Rate, IM.Title, IM.CID, IM.QTY, IM.DateCompleted, C.Client, U.Name, R.FrequencyUnit, R.FrequencyDuration, R.RBID
ORDER BY IM.DateCompleted ASC;
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If multiple RecurringItem records exist, which one do you want to display ... and *why*? ie Use the earliest or latest, according to ID, date, etcetera.

Comment: *use a MAX() on that value* Not if they need to include other columns from that table in the `select` list as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options

- You can drop `R.RBID` from your `select` and `group by` clauses
- Create a unique key on Rate, Title, FrequencyUnit, FrequencyDuration so you don't get "similar items
- Only grab one R.RBID per Rate, Title, FrequencyUnit, FrequencyDuration

If its the last one you want you can use row_number to grab one and only one RBID per (rate,title, frequencyunit and frequencyduration)

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT IM.imid, IM.userid, IM.clientid, IM.rate, 
                IM.title, IM.cid,  IM.qty, IM.datecompleted, 
                C.client, U.name, R.frequencyunit, R.frequencyduration, 
                R.rbid, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY R.rate, R.title, R.frequencyunit, R.frequencyduration 
                    ORDER BY R.rbid ) rn 
         FROM   itemmisc IM 
                LEFT JOIN clients C 
                       ON C.clientid = IM.clientid 
                LEFT JOIN users U 
                       ON U.userid = IM.userid 
                LEFT JOIN recurringitem R 
                       ON ( R.clientid = C.clientid 
                            AND IM.rate = R.rate 
                            AND IM.title = R.title ) 
        WHERE   (IM.CID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#CID#">) 
            AND   (IM.Invoiced = 0)
         GROUP  BY IM.imid, IM.userid, IM.clientid, IM.rate, 
                   IM.title, IM.cid, IM.qty, IM.datecompleted, 
                   C.client, U.name, R.frequencyunit, R.frequencyduration, 
                   R.rbid) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1 
ORDER  BY im.datecompleted ASC
```

Note: You may define "similar items" by modifying the members of the `partition BY`

Comment: Thanks for quick in depth response. Stil trying to get it to work, will pick up again tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Still Having trouble with it:

Comment: Added to your answer. Sorry the query didn't format properly.

Comment: @SteveOntologic your [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1726713) got rejected  by the community as an "attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." So in the future you should probably put that stuff in a comment instead of an edit. That said to clear your error you need to alias one or both of the rate fields. For example `IM.Rate as IM_RATE`.